# How can I run something in a thread with passenger?

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, passenger

I'm using Phusion Passenger with my nginx to deploy rails/sinatra applications, and I'm currently having a problem.

I want to run a class that checks for new submissions to reddit.com every 30 seconds. But since passenger shuts down the application after x seconds of idle time, it won't keep checking.

Yes, I've tried to set passenger_pool_idle_time to 0, but it still shuts it down.

If you want more details, see the application at [github](https://gist.github.com/905f499106d5a8a63e9e)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason you can't use a cron job to call a Ruby script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use cron to call into your server ever so often, to make sure it's still running. What may be happening is that passenger is starting up an initial process, then forking it for each worker process it needs later.  After awhile, it kills the initial process (thinking it has spawned all the children it ever needs), so setting it to not do that might fix it.

Comment: Sorry for the late accept + answer. Yes, I have no idea why it did not occur to me to use a regular cronjob. There was absolutely no need to run it as a thread in the spawned passenger process. Thanks!